# How to change an image from the DOM in a particular browser width without using media-queries

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design, media-queries

I have an img tag in the DOM.

```
<div class="some-div">
     <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-networks-and-media-flat-icons/133/Social_Media_Socialmedia_network_share_socialnetwork_network-09-128.png">
</div>
```

Now when the browser width become 768px (actually for the tab,smartphone) I need to change the src of the img tag. That means simply the image will be changed to a another one. Example:-

```
<div class="some-div">
     <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-networks-and-media-flat-icons/133/Social_Media_Socialmedia_network_share_socialnetwork_network-09-128.png">
</div>
```

Remember I cant use the background-image property in the css for some reason here so would not be able to write media-queries like this @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)

I need to change it via JS or anyhow. Can you help? Thanks a ton.

Comment: Add a callback to `window.onresize` event to check the window size and change the image `src` when window width `< 768`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Remember I cant use the background-image property in the css for some reason here so would not be able to write media-queries like this @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)

If it's *specifically* that you can't use `background-image`, but you can use media queries, then:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    img.small {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    img.big {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

...and in your markup:

```
<img class="big" src="/path/to/big/image.png">
<img class="small" src="/path/to/small/image.png">
```

If you can't use media queries *at all*, then:

```
<img data-big="/path/to/big/image.png" data-small="/path/to/small/image.png">
```

and

```
(function() {
    var lastSizeAttr = null;
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); // the list is live
    var resizeTimer = 0;

    window.addEventListener("resize", maybeResize);

    function maybeResize() {
        if (resizeTimer) {
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        }
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(imageResize, 100); // Wait 100ms
    }

    function imageResize() {
        var attr = favorite_width_prop_here < 769 ? "data-small" : "data-big";
        var img;
        var n;

        resizeTimer = 0;
        if (attr !== lastSizeAttr) {
            lastSizeAttr = attr;
            for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
                img = list[n];
                img.src = img.getAttribute(attr);
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

...or similar at the *end* of your HTML (so the elements are there to be found by `getElementsByTagName`). Note the `favorite_width_prop_here`, I don't immediately recall which property to use if you're not using jQuery. :-)

Comment: Hey @T.J thanks man. I was so stupid. Yes it can be done by simply hiding one at the big screen. No need to use JS at all. Didn't click in mind first. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the width of window size.

```
function calculateWidth(){
   if(window.outerWidth <= 768){
      var imgTag =  document.getElementElementById('someImage');
      imgTag.src = "imageForTab.jpg"; //here your small image would be for tab
    }
}

//attaching the function on window resize
window.addEventListener('resize', calculateWidth);  

<body onload="calculateWidth()"> //calling the function on body onload
```

Pleae put id on your image tag.

```
 <img id="someImage" src="https.....
```

This is handeling only the image which is given with this id ('someImage').